# Basic Python Class Yields TypeError

Tags: python, class

I'm fairly new to Python. Here, I'm creating a class to represent a blob-like structure. However, my code yields the following error:

> TypeError: add() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

```
class Blob:
    mass = 0
    xvals = []
    yvals = []
    correlationVal = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Blob.mass = 0
        Blob.correlationVal = 0

    def add(x, y, newCorrel):
        Blob.correlationVal = computeCorrelation(newCorrel)
        Blob.mass += 1
        Blob.xvals.append(x)
        Blob.yvals.append(y)

    def computeCorrelation(newCorrel):
        prevCorrel = Blob.correlationVal*Blob.mass
        updatedCorrel = (prevCorrel + newCorrel)/(Blob.mass + 1)
        return updatedCorrel

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test1 = Blob()
    print(test1.mass)
    test1.add(0, 0, 12)
    print(test1.mass)
    print(test1.correlationVal)
    test1.add(0, 1, 10)
    print(test1.mass)
    print(test1.correlationVal)
    test1.add(1, 1, 11)
    print(test1.mass)
    print(test1.correlationVal)
    print(test1.xvals)
    print(test1.yvals)
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how am I giving 4 inputs, when I supply 3?

Note: The error results from the "test1.add(0, 0, 12)" line.

Comment: your methods should accept self as the first parameter.. ie def add(self, x, y, newCorrel):

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of self in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: You should spend some time reading the [Classes section in the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes) - you may have to revisit it a number of times:  9.1) Names and Objects and 9.2) Scopes and Namespaces subsections are pretty important to understand. If an attribute is intended to be an *instance* attribute ```self``` is typically used for the name of the instance and it is always the first argument passed to an instance method.

Answer (score 4):

Your instance methods are missing the `self` reference:

```
def computeCorrelation(self, newCorrel)
#                       ^

def add(self, x, y, newCorrel)
#        ^
```

The first parameter passed by an instance method is a reference to that instance of the class. So your `add` method *should* take 4 arguments but you will only be required to pass 3 when the method is called from an instance of the class. Python passes the reference to that instance for you.

---

More so, you are referencing your attributes from the class itself as `Blob.some_attribute`, you should instead use `self`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.mass = 0
    self.correlationVal = 0
```

This modifies those attributes only on that instance of the class which is what you intend with `__init__`. The same should apply to the other methods.

Comment: Additionally, the methods should refer to the instance `self` rather than the class `Blob`. The first line of `__init__(self)` would then look like: `self.mass = 0`

Comment: I see. Thanks everyone for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

in a class, the first argument of a function is `self`. When in your main, you call `test1.add(0, 0, 12)`, python call `test1.add(test1,0, 0, 12)`, so now he has 4 argument.

```
class Blob:
    mass = 0
    xvals = []
    yvals = []
    correlationVal = 0

def __init__(self):
    self.mass = 0
    self.correlationVal = 0

def add(self,x, y, newCorrel):
    self.correlationVal = computeCorrelation(self,newCorrel)
    self.mass += 1
    self.xvals.append(x)
    self.yvals.append(y)
```

Comment: `self` is just a convention btw, but this is a good one ! let's keep it

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to a Python class method needs to be `self` i.e. `def add(self, x, y, newCorrel):` instead of `def add(x, y, newCorrel):`.

Self is implicitly passed to class instance methods when they are called, hence why 4 arguments are being passed instead of just the 3 you explicitly pass.

N.B. Non-instance methods (static methods) don't require self as their first parameter. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) for more details.